# In Graphiti, how to put an editor on a label attached to a Figure

Tags: javascript

I was trying to create an editable label like the one in the example connection_labeledit_inplace.

The problem I have is that I want to attach the label to a custom VectorFigure in place of a Connection. When doing that the label is just part of the figure and don't launch the editor.

```
ivr.shape.menu.MenuItem = graphiti.VectorFigure.extend({

NAME:"ivr.shape.menu.MenuItem",

MyOutputPortLocator : graphiti.layout.locator.Locator.extend({
    init: function(parent)
    {
        this._super(parent);
    },
    relocate:function(index, figure){
        var w = figure.getParent().getWidth();
        var h = figure.getParent().getHeight();

        figure.setPosition(w, h/2);
    }
}),

/**
 * @constructor
 * Creates a new figure element which are not assigned to any canvas.
 *
 */
init: function( width, height) {
    this._super();
    this.setBackgroundColor( new graphiti.util.Color(200,200,200));
    this.setColor(new graphiti.util.Color(50,50,50));

    // set some good defaults
    //
    if(typeof width === "undefined"){
        this.setDimension(100, 15);
    }
    else{
        this.setDimension(width, height);
    }

    // add port
    var outputLocator = new this.MyOutputPortLocator(this);
    this.createPort("output",outputLocator);

    this.label = new graphiti.shape.basic.Label("I'm a Label");
    this.label.setColor("#0d0d0d");
    this.label.setFontColor("#0d0d0d");
    this.addFigure(this.label, new graphiti.layout.locator.LeftLocator(this));

    this.label.installEditor(new graphiti.ui.LabelInplaceEditor());
},


repaint : function(attributes)
{
    if(this.repaintBlocked===true || this.shape===null){
        return;
    }

    if (typeof attributes === "undefined") {
        attributes = {};
    }

    var box = this.getBoundingBox();
    var center = box.getCenter();
    var path = ["M",box.x,",",box.y];
    path.push("l", box.w-10, ",0");
    path.push("l10,", box.h/2);
    path.push("l-10,", box.h/2);
    path.push("L",box.x,",", box.getBottomLeft().y);
    path.push("Z");
    var strPath = path.join("");
    attributes.path = strPath;

    this._super(attributes);
},


/**
 * @method
 * Called by the framework. Don't call them manually.
 *
 * @private
 **/
createShapeElement:function()
{
    // create dummy line
    return this.canvas.paper.path("M0 0L1 1");
}
```

});

For this example I put the label on the left of the Figure but obviously I'll make a Locator that puts the label ON the figure (just in case it changes something)

Up to me the issue is coming from the way the 'graphiti.Canvas.getBestFigure()' works. The function check only over elements directly attached to the 'graphity.Canvas' Also, the function is missing some recursion to propagates the event on the children.

Answer (score 0):

Graphiti provides a CenterLocator.
All events like dblClick can be catched by the figure.

....did youuse thelatest version?

Comment: Sure I took the latest and I know I can catch click on a figure. The problem is that the event doesn't propagates to children figures of a figure attached to the canvas.

Comment: Version 1.0.0 is out and the docs tells it should be working now. Great.